# Why was Chloe Decker not shocked/surprised when seeing Lucifer in S01 finale?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

Why isn't Chloe Decker on season 1 finale shocked/surprised with Lucifer being healthy after being shot?  She is like nothing weird happened when she saw him being shot. She didn't even ask him how it is possible, she just accepts the fact 'I died, but I'm ok'. Meanwhile the whole season she doesn't believe he is immortal. So what's up here?

Comment: Because she finally realizes Lucifer is the real deal? Or at least not completely human?

Answer (score 4):

Your premise is wrong, almost immediately after she wakes they have the following conversation:

> Chloe: He was firing at you, why aren't you ... more dead?
>
> Lucifer: You're having a very hard time with the immortal, aren't you?

So while she indeed drops it quite quickly, she at least is surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Chloe is a woman of feelings, not beliefs. She needs to see that more than one time, she doesn't believe he's immortal just because he said.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found, or giving us the rationale behind your ideas and conclusions. I hope you enjoy participating.

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning in stackexchange.com . Nice to meet this community!

Comment: Or perhaps, Chloe is an angel, but in person, not in specie or race.

Comment: Or perhaps, Chloe is angel, but in person, not in specie or race.